# next.js & express.js have an insecure transport issue

Tags: express, security, next.js

I am using next.js and express.js, but internal security tool found there is an insecure transport issue when do `expressApp.listen(4501` below.

the details of the issue:
The call uses an unencrypted protocol instead of an encrypted protocol to communicate with the server. All communication over HTTP, FTP, or gopher is unauthenticated and unencrypted.

Please suggest how to fix it. Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
const next = require('next');
const express = require('express');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

const app = next({ dev });
const expressApp = express();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  expressApp.listen(4501, (err) => {
    if (err) {
       throw err;
    }
  })
})
```

tried to read official document and search in stackoverflow, cannot find any solutions